# Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, slider, gallery

On single woocommerce product pages I am trying to add the product gallery slider navigation and also correct the thumbnails to display correctly.

I have added the theme support for the wc-product-gallery-slider as follows

```
<?php

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cws_child_theme_setup' );
function cws_child_theme_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'orgafit', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
?>
```

[Link to Single Product Page](https://poshreffcosmetics.co.za/product/liquid-matte-lipsticks/)

Answer (score 4):

You can add the slider navigation using WordPress filters.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'cuswoo_update_woo_flexslider_options' );
/** 
 * Filer WooCommerce Flexslider options - Add Navigation Arrows
 */
function cuswoo_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {

    $options['directionNav'] = true;

    return $options;
}
```

This will add slider navigation options on left and right. Then we just have to add CSS.

```
 ul.flex-direction-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;}

li.flex-nav-prev {float: left;}
li.flex-nav-next {float: right;}
a.flex-next {visibility:hidden;}
a.flex-prev {visibility:hidden;}

a.flex-next::after {
    visibility:visible;content: '\f054';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;   
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.flex-prev::before {
    visibility:visible;
    content: '\f053';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';   
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.flex-direction-nav li a {
    color: #ccc;
}
ul.flex-direction-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The a.flex-next::after and ::before uses Font Awesome content, so make sure you add this according to the Font Awesome version you're using.

Comment: @Dharman - I am using font awesome 5.  I see the nav now - how could I change the thumbnails to display in a row and hidden rather than in a grid like that. similar to `(http://poshreff.co.za/shop/home/21-40-liquid-matte-lipsticks.html#/26-color_lipstick-prbc28bubbly_pink)`

Comment: thank you. I cant seem to align the nav arrows equally across the slider - did i add something incorrectly

Comment: Your WP theme has some CSS styles missing. 

The <li> under .flex-direction-nav ul should be aligned. You can do that by adding class li.flex-nav-prev {float: left;}
li.flex-nav-next {float: right;}
If the above classes are added, then seems like these classes are not being applied to your <li> under flex-direction-nav.

Also this class is creating issues. This is putting a bullet before the arrows ul > li:before { }

Comment: thank you. I have managed to remove the bullet, but cannot seem to align the arrows. any suggestions please? :)

Comment: Try this CSS. ul.flex-direction-nav > :first-child { float: left; }  ul.flex-direction-nav > :nth-child(2) { float: right;margin-top: 0em !important; }

Comment: Thank you ! that is it.  is there a way to  change the thumbnails to display in a row and hidden rather than in a grid like that. similar to `(http://poshreff.co.za/shop/home/21-40-liquid-matte-lipsticks.html#/26-color_lipstick-prbc28bubbly_pink)`

Comment: I got it what you're looking for. Woocommerce uses flexslider for product page slider. Checkout this link: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Comment: thank you ! do you know how i could integrate this into the theme?

Comment: @Abubaker Thank you for this, when you view the product an image in lightbox mode the font awesome icons overlay the lightbox, is there a way to make them disappear when you enlarge the image via lightbox?